# Handling grammatical gender with Gettext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gettext

I'm looking for a simple-proper-elegant way to handle grammatical gender with Gettext in a Rails application, the same way plurals are handled with `n_()` method.

<del>This has no interest in english, since words don't vary with gender, but it does when translating into spanish.</del> His / her is a good use case in english. This is really needed when translating into spanish.

An example:

Considering users Pablo (male) and Ana María (female).

```
_('%{user} is tall') & {:user => user.name}
```

Should be translated to

```
'Pablo es alto'
'Ana María es alta'
```

Of course, we have access to `user.gender`

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using standard gettext features this can be solved using contexts. Like calling appropriate:

```
p_('Male', '%{user} is tall')
```

or

```
p_('Female', '%{user} is tall')
```

This will generate two separate strings in gettext catalogs marking them with "Male" and "Female" contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no.  This is a limitation of the gettext system--aside from number, linguistic features are based on the language you key off of.  If you were to key all of your strings in Spanish, it would work.

Another option would be to append a character to the string for translation's sake, and then strip it off.

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but the basic idea in psuedo-code would be:

```
if (user.sex == male) {
    strip_last_char(_('%{user} is tall♂') & {:user => user.name})
} else {
    strip_last_char(_('%{user} is tall♀') & {:user => user.name})
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What about using the [plural form](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_mono/gettext.html#Plural-forms) mechanism of gettext. Usually a parameter n is used to distinguish between singular and plural forms.

Now imagine to use n to define your gender instead of an amount. Thus p.ex. n=1 means female (and not singular) and n=2 (or n>1) means female (and not plural).

```
n = user.male? ? 1 : 0
n_('%{user} is tall', '%{user} is tall', n) & {:user => user.name}
```

Comment: thx for the correct ruby syntax dgilperez. if you use user.gender instead of n, like I proposed, then this could be used also for other languages with more the two gender forms.Also be aware to correctly setup Plural-Forms (here: Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n == 1 ? 0 : 1;) in your messages.po

Comment: No! A million times no! The whole point of the plural forms feature is that different languages have different numbers of plural forms or may not have different forms for singular and plural at all. Never ever do that!